# Modular Arithmetic Prime Proof Lemma

Tags: proof-writing, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, coprime

Let $a, b, x \in Z$, let $n ∈ N$ and let $h = hcf(a, n)$. Suppose that $h | b$, let $a'=\frac{a}{h}, b'=\frac{b}{h}$ and $n'=\frac{n}{h}$. Prove that $a'$ is comprime to $n'$.

By Bezout's lemma, there exist integers $u$ and $v$ such that $ax+nv=h$. Dividing by $h$ and using the properties given we get $a'x+n'y=1$. Let $h'=hcf(a',n')$. $h' | a$ and $h'|n'$, so by a lemma $h'|a'x+n'y=1$. Hence, if $h'|LHS$, $h'|RHS$, so $h' = 1$ or $h'=-1$. Since highest common factor must be positive, $h'=1$, so $a'$ and $n'$ are coprime.

I'm unsure of my method after dividing by $h$. Could someone please check this ?

Comment: your proof seems valid to me, there's nothing wrong.

Comment: @DS Thanks buddy. Sorry for all the questions, I just want to make sure my answers are correct as solutions are mainly unavailable.

Comment: No need to be sorry for asking questions :)

Comment: Yes, but solutions are not unavailable. There are many duplicates.

Comment: Precisely what are you unsure of?

Comment: @DietrichBurde My proof is different which is why I have asked as I wanted feedback on my proof.